# How to Install Web page package in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, package

How do I install web page package to use it in visual studio 2013?
I want to use web page class.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NuGet:
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages